# IL Compiler for .NET?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, intermediate-language

This may be a dumb question, but is there a compiler for IL code, similar to that shown by Reflector in IL mode?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[ilasm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilasm), it comes with the .NET Framework.

The complete reference is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

yes ilasm, it comes with the .NET Framework.
but you need the SDK DeComplier

I'm looking for it my self

Comment: For .Net 2.0 you need to download and install the "Microsoft .Net Framework 2.0 SDK". Then ildasm.exe is typically in C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\v2.0\Bin.